# Android: Send a file to be saved on a database in a server

Tags: android, mysql, database, file, server

I'm trying to send a file from an android application. I want this file to be stored in a mysql database on a server.

From my research online, I've only found how to send the file to the server, that's all.

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple options for this. Store on server filesystem, Blob type, use the response if it is in JSON format and de serialise into objects. Pick and choose.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [BLOB type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html).

It is used to store binary data, in mysql.

But the recommended way is to upload the file to your server file system, then insert the path of your your file, not the file itself.

Comment: @meda..sir can u please look into this and help me..[how to save 2 images into the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098271/how-to-upload-more-than-one-image-to-servermysql-database-using-php-and-androi).thanks in advance..!!